# SQL Server Management Studio saves .sql file with binary character

Tags: sql-server, ssms, accurev

While saving .sql files from SQL Server Management Studio in to my local windows folder, it looks to be including some binary characters making AccuRev comparisons impossible. I looked for possible save options and couldn't locate any. and couldn't find any. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Could it be that those files are stored in **UTF-8** and have the UTF-8 Byte-Order Mark ("BOM", 3 bytes at the beginning of the file)?? If so: can you tell AccuRev to ignore/interpret those files as UTF-8?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yes, I see a weird character in the beginning of the file in AccuRev. I tried performing a keep operation in AccuRev and asked it to consider it as a text file. That doesn't seem to help either. Not sure if I'm missing something here.

Comment: The only options I see in AccuRev v6.2.2 are text, ptext & binary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't tell AccuRev to handle this as UTF-8 files (this **sucks** - these days, **all** software should really know about UTF-8 and handle it correctly!), then you might need to do something in SQL Server Management Studio instead.

When you have a SQL statement open and you click on "File > Save", in the "Save" dialog, there is a little down-arrow to the right of the <kbd>Save</kbd> button:

[image]

If you click that (instead of just clicking on the button itself), you can select "Save with Encoding", which allows you to *pick* what encoding to use for your files - pick something like the Windows-1252 Western European - that should not have any UTF-8 Byte-Order Mark bytes at the start:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped!

Comment: @rsreji: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Answer (score 0):

AccuRev does handle UTF-8 character encoding. However, older versions may not have that capability.

Make sure that the file is being saved using UTF-8. Anything else will have binary content and should be typed as such.

Answer (score 0):

When you export sql files from MS SQL Server Management Studio in unicode (by default), it puts a "FF FE BOM" at the front of the file which forces programs to treat it as binary. Exporting as ANSI solved it. Choose "Save as ANSI Text".